# Ember Serializer is not serializing embbed records

Tags: serialization, ember.js

I am trying to serialize my payload from server, but it is not working.

Here is an example of my payload:

```
events:[{
  id: "57f358856c616cf434fd0500"
  annotations:[{_id: "57f358856c616cf434ff0500", desc: "hello world"}]
}]
```

I want to change annotations _id to id.

Here is my serializer:

```
//event.js
export default ActiveModelSerializer.extend(DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin, {
  attrs:{
    annotations:{embedded:'always'}
  }
});

//annotation.js
export default ActiveModelSerializer.extend(DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin,{      
  attrs:{
    id: '_id',
  },
});
```

Even though I am using `DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin`, it still doesn't work. Can anyone help me please? Thank you.

Comment: What version of ember and ember-data are you using? Also are you using an Ruby backend? I ask because ActiveModelSerialzier is maybe not what you want if you are using something else.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming whatever versions of ember and ember-data you are using will be making use of the **Ember Data 2.0 Serializer** (this means using the  [JSONAPISerializer](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.JSONAPISerializer.html#content)).

So instead of what you have in your `annotations.js` I think you want a file in `app/serializers/annotation.js`, assuming you're not using [pods](https://ember-cli.com/user-guide/#pod-structure).

```
// path: app/serializers/annotation.js
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.JSONAPISerializer.extend({
  primaryKey: '_id'
});
```

**Working Code Example I created in Ember Twiddle** [EmbeddedRecords with _id](https://ember-twiddle.com/1786dffcbf2b91ab7dd39f2f3f0b0f4b?openFiles=serializers.chapter.js%2C)

Ember API reference: http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.JSONAPISerializer.html#property_primaryKey